# Probability that a particular number occurs finitely many times in an infinite sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given is an infinite sequence, $a_0, a_1, a_2,...,a_n,...$. 
And each $a_i=k\in{1,...N}$ with a probability $0<p_k<1$. 
So an example of the infinite sequence being: $1,2,2,3,1,2,3,6,4,3,2,6,7,4,6,....$ for $N=7$. 
Now let the subset of all such infinite sequences be $S$ (for a given $N$). There would exist a subset of $S$, $S'$ where the number of times a particular number, say $i$ occurs is finite. 
So I need to find the probability of this event, i.e. the probability corresponding to this set $S'$.

What I observed was that probability of each (individual) sequence would be $0$. And for any given $N_0>0$, probability that the number $i$ doesn't occur after $a_{N_0}$ is $0$. But how do I "sum" over all the elements of $S'$ is not quite obvious to me. 
I did some research and found out that measure theory may have answers for this question of mine, but I don't know anything about it, so can anybody throw some light? (Though it would be nice, if the answer requires as much elementary math as it can) 
It would be even better if someone could give an intuition for the distribution for this.

Comment: The probability of $i$ not occurring $m$ times is $(1-p_i)^m$.

Comment: @copper.hat, Yes, I know that. Thats what I used in above, in the line: "probability that the number i doesn't occur after $a_{N_0}$ is $0$. So what is it that I am missing?

Comment: I don't understand the issue, you know that the probability is less than any positive number. Hence zero.

Comment: The best tool to use for this question is the [Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma). You should find that the answer is $0$. (Observing that an individual sequence has probability $0$ isn't helpful, since that's true for any sequence regardless of whether it has finitely or infinitely many occurrences of a given integer.)

Comment: @copper.hat, I cannot quite state _formally_ what I want to say. We want $P(S')$. And we know that for any $N_0>0$, $P(a_n\neq i \forall n>N_0)=0$. Now how do I put these together?

Comment: @Greg Martin, exactly. Okay, thanks for providing the answer though I don't quite know about the lemma.